# Problems with plain tex and ngerman.sty

Tags: languages, plain-tex, german

I tried to typeset a plain TeX document with the `ngerman.sty` macro set. Unfortunately, I get the following output for a simple test file containing nothing but `\input ngerman.sty\end`:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
(./q.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/german/ngerman.sty
v2.5e 1998-07-08
ngerman -- \language number for ngerman undefined, default 255 used,
ngerman -- Please read "gerdoc.tex" how to install hyphenation patterns.) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

First, I'd like to know if this is an error and if yes, how do I fix it? The same error appears when I try to typeset the document with `xetex`, `etex`, or `pdftex`. I am a bit new to plain TeX and this is the first time I try to do something slightly complex after reading the TeXbook. I use TeXlive on Ubuntu 14.04.1. As far as I am concerned, all packages from the TeXlive distribution are installed on my system

Comment: As far as you know you can't use a `.sty` file in plain TeX (please correct me if I'm wrong). You *can* use (most) LaTeX packages with eplain (not bundled with TeXlive). What are you trying to do? In XeTeX, I can type `\uselanguage{german}` to use correct hyphenation.

Comment: You need a format where the languages have been loaded, which is not the case for `plain.fmt`.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel ngerman.sty provides some macros that make typesetting German easier, notably it makes `"` active so you can typeset umlauts with `"a` instead of `\\"a`. The documentation for `ngerman.sty` explicitly states that it can be used this way in plain TeX.

Comment: @egreg Is there such a format that is otherwise like `plain.fmt` in TeXlive?

Comment: Perhaps not what you asked for, but in XeTeX, you can simply type `ä` in UTF-8 and your document (with OpenType fonts) compiles fine. I use a special `.Xmodmap` to make it easier to type characters with diacritics.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel That's interesting.

Comment: Just have a look at https://github.com/marcelkorpel/dotfiles/blob/master/.Xmodmap for inspiration (with this, I can type `ä` with AltGr+Shift+a).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Thank you, I use a German layout so this is not needed. I prefer to use the computer modern fonts though, so maybe I have to use some trickery with latin modern to get them to run with Unicode input.

Comment: But don't you *have* to type `\"a\"o\ss`, etc., then?

Comment: And indeed, see http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern (provides OpenType versions of all those fonts).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel `ngerman.sty` makes `"` active so you can type `"a"o"s` instead. Additionally, `german.sty` provides some special macros for the rather weird hyphenation rules of the old orthography, where `backen` is hypenated as `bak-ken` and `Schiffahrt` as `Schiff-fahrt`. They also provide macros that create make-shift German quote characters „“ by lowering the English ” character. Very much needed for typesetting with the computer modern fonts.

Comment: Ah, I thought that the default hyphenation patterns in `dehyphn.tex` were sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hyphenation patterns for the various languages must be loaded at format creation. The `plain.fmt` file is built with patterns only for English.

You can enable languages by creating a format yourself:

1. from the terminal run

   ```
   pdftex -etex -ini "\input bplain\dump"
   ```
2. send the command

   ```
   mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/web2c/pdftex
   ```
3. send the command

   ```
   mv bplain.* $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/web2c/pdftex/
   ```
4. run TeX on your file by

   ```
   pdftex -fmt bplain fuzxxl
   ```

   (of course, use the real file name)

You may want to create an alias for this, or a special command for your front end.

For XeTeX this is not necessary, because the format loads all available languages. However the language you need is named

```
\lang@ngerman
```

instead of the expected `\l@ngerman`. Add the following incantation at the beginning of your file

```
\catcode`@=11
\let\l@ngerman\lang@ngerman
\catcode`@=12
```

and you should be OK.

Comment: Given that I would like to use XeTeX, is this also the way to proceed, but with `XeTeX` substituted for `pdftex`?

Comment: @FUZxxl No, that won't work because one has to use UTF-8 patterns. I'll give a try.

Comment: @FUZxxl It was easier than expected, see the addition to my answer. However, I can't guarantee that the old `ngerman.sty` will work as expected. You're best served with LaTeX, in my opinion.